# Help me understand product rule for matrix differentiation

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I am trying to compute a Hessian for an optimization problem but I seem to be stuck at the required differentiations. I have the following objects:

$M=[A-BX]=[C-DY]$ where $M$,  $A$ and $C$ are $s \times 1$, $B$ is $s \times k$, $X$ is $k\times 1$ and $D$ is $s\times r$ and $Y$ is $r \times 1$. Furthermore, I have a matrix $E$ which is $s \times s$.

I am trying to compute the Hessian by a product rule because the expectation of $M$ is zero (It is a moment condition).

The object I am trying to differentiate with respect to $X$ is the following:

$Q=-2\times M^TWB$

I can write the whole thing out and take the derivatives directly -I know the solution- but I want to apply the product rule with the above in mind. This yields:

$D_X(Q)= -2\times D_X(M^T)WB-2\times M^TWD_X(B)$

The first term yields what is required in this example, ie, $2 B^TWB$, which is $k\times k$, but the question is now how to deal with the dimensions of the second term. I know this is a zero matrix which should be of dimension $k \times k$ too, but as it stands it is $1 \times dim[G_X (B)]$.

Is my logic on the product rule correct? How do I make the second term fit? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let me use uppercase for matrices and lowercase for column vectors.

Writing the function, differential, and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 q &= -2 B^TW^Tm \cr
dq &= -2 B^TW^T\,dm = 2 B^TW^TB\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial q}{\partial x} &= 2 B^TW^TB \cr\cr
}$$
Your product rule for the gradient is incorrect
$$\eqalign{
 \nabla(AB) &\ne (\nabla A)B + A(\nabla B) \cr
}$$

The product rule for differentials is what you want
$$\eqalign{
 d(AB) = (dA)B + A(dB) \cr
}$$ where the differential of a constant matrix is a zero matrix of the same dimensions.